Calculating definite integral using complex analysis
I'm trying to calculate this integral using Complex Analysis:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^{7/3}\,\ln\left(x\right)}
{\left(x^{4} + 1\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
$$
I understand that I can calculate it using integration over a ring with the real axis removed but this just will take too much time:
And the residues here are very ugly, because of the derivates.
So, please, tell me how can I calculate it correctly and efficiently.

Have you tried integrating over the classical dogbone contour?

Didn't know that the dogbone contour is called this way, but yes I've tried, and the calculations are very complex and ugly.

If you show your attempt, then I will help you.  HINT:  Just analyze the contour integral $$\oint_{C_{DB}} \frac{z^\alpha}{(z^4+1)^2},dz$$Then differentiate the result with respect to $\alpha$ and set $\alpha =7/3$

Thanks a lot for a hint! I think I now see how can I calculate it. I prefer not to show my attempt because it's in my barely readable cursive ;)

@P.Dvas You show your attempt by editing the post to include MathJax, not with an image of your handwriting.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
A $\ds{\underline{\large Real}}$ Integration:
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{7/3}\,\ln\pars{x} \over
\pars{x^{4} + 1}^{2}}\dd x} \sr{x^{4}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}
{1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1/6}\,\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x + 1}^{2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.{1 \over 16}\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\color{red}{\nu}\ -\ 1} \over \pars{x + 1}^{\color{red}{\nu}\ +\ \pars{\color{red}{2\ -\ \nu}}}\,\,}\,\,\,
\dd x\right\vert_{\,\nu\ =\ 5/6}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.{1 \over 16}\partiald{}{\nu}{\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{\nu}}\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{2 - \nu}} \over \Gamma\pars{2}}
\right\vert_{\,\nu\ =\ 5/6}
\end{align}
See here. Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{7/3}\,\ln\pars{x} \over
\pars{x^{4} + 1}^{2}}\dd x} =
\left.{1 \over 16}\partiald{}{\nu}\Gamma\pars{\nu}\Gamma\pars{1 - \nu}\pars{1 - \nu}
\right\vert_{\,\nu\ =\ 5/6}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.{\pi \over 16}\partiald{\bracks{\csc\pars{\pi\nu}\pars{1 - \nu}}}{\nu}\right\vert_{\,\nu\ =\ 5/6}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over 16}\bracks{\rule{0pt}{5mm}-\csc\pars{\pi\nu} -
\pi\pars{1 - \nu}\cot\pars{\pi\nu}\csc\pars{\pi\nu}}_{\,\nu\ =\ 5/6}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{\pi \over 48}\pars{\root{3}\pi - 6}}} \approx -0.03656 \\ &
\end{align}
